# Why single out the miracle with the aron in כהושעת אלים? And why in that spot?

Tags: miracle, ark-aron-kodesh, hoshanos

In the hoshana כהושעת אלים, most of it talks about the miracles of Yetzias Mitzrayim and the splitting of the sea (letters א-נ), then moves on to the circuits around the mizbe'ach (ס-ע), then - suddenly - back to another miracle, the punishment of the Plishtim that forced them to have to return the aron, as described in 1 Shmuel 5-6.

1. Why is this miracle singled out from all the other ones that have happened since Yetzias Mitzrayim?
2. Why is it separated from them in the piyut?

Comment: +1 but you have to realize that the Peh of Pilei and Pleshes fits there in the alphabetical order.

Comment: @user6591: pilei is a pretty generic word, so it could apply to any miracle. Pleshes isn't relevant - it's the second word of the צ line, and in none of the other lines is there any significance to the alphabetical order of the 2nd word.

Comment: Conceded on both points.